# Hangman game, cant get the program to display/finish game upon winning

Tags: java

The program compiles and runs. the problem is that while playing if I enter a correct letter that is in the word, it picks up that it is correct but doesn't "acknowledge it", so to speak. it just keeps repeating unless you hit a wrong letter and in that case it works right and displays properly, as well as, counts remaining guesses and ends after the 6th guess, going back to main. other than that it seems to be running fine for a simple beginner program. I don't know how to make it work like it is supposed to and have been at it for several hours trying to figure it out. any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I put as little in as I thought needed to fix the problem, again thanks for any help and sorry for the length.

Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Hangmangame
{
   public static void main( String [] args)
   {    
      Scanner keyBd = new Scanner( System.in );
      char selection = ' ';
      do{
         System.out.printf("\nWelcome to Hangman!\n");
         System.out.println("1. Play Game");
         System.out.println("2. Rules");
         System.out.println("3. Exit");
         System.out.print  ("Selection: ");
         System.out.println();

         selection = keyBd.next().charAt(0);

            switch (selection)
            {
               case '1': Play(); break;//Play Game
               case '2': Rules(); break;//go to rules  
               case '3': break;//exit program
               default: 
                  System.out.println("\nInvalid selection!");
                  System.out.println("Press any key+<Enter> to continue...\n");
                  keyBd.next();
            }//end switch 
      }//end loop
      while(selection != '3');   
   }//end main

   public static void Play()
   {  
      Letter guesses = new Letter();
      Gallows printGallows = new Gallows();
      Word WordtoGuess = new Word(); 
      Hint YourHint = new Hint();     

      String[] Words = { "armor","dwarf","rogue","remix","shank","toxin","viper","wrath","wreck","zones"}; 


      ArrayList<Hint> Hints = new ArrayList<>();
         Hints.add(new Hint("often made out of metal"));
         Hints.add(new Hint("a short mythological blacksmith"));
         Hints.add(new Hint("a scoundrel or rascal"));
         Hints.add(new Hint("edited or changed"));
         Hints.add(new Hint("homemade sharpened object"));
         Hints.add(new Hint("a poisonous substance"));
         Hints.add(new Hint("poisonous reptile or vehicle"));
         Hints.add(new Hint("retributary punishment"));
         Hints.add(new Hint("scattered debris in an area"));
         Hints.add(new Hint("pre-selected designated areas"));      

      Random rnum = new Random();
      int n;
      System.out.println("start game");
      n = rnum.nextInt(10);
      WordtoGuess.setIndex(n);
      WordtoGuess.setWord(Words[n]);
      String word = Words[n];
      Hint hint = Hints.get(n);
      System.out.println("You have 6 chances to guess the word, good luck!!");
      System.out.println(" --\n   |\n   |\n   |\n_____\n");    //gallows
      do{
         while( printGallows.hasGuesses() /*&& WordtoGuess.Win()*/) //if this block is commented out the program will continue to play until all 6 attempts are used, ending the game.
         {                                                          //if not commented out the program will always tell you that you have won without ever asking for input guesses.

            System.out.println(hint);
            printGallows.printGallows();
            guesses.guessLetter();
            if ( WordtoGuess.Contains( guesses.getLetter() ) || WordtoGuess.NotContain( guesses.getLetter() ) ) 
            {
               System.out.println( "That letter has already been guessed... Please try another." );
            } 
            else 
            {
               if (WordtoGuess.ContainsGuess( guesses.getLetter() ) ) 
               {
                  WordtoGuess.CompareGuess( guesses.getLetter() , printGallows );
               } 
               else 
               {
                  printGallows.setGuesses();
               }
            }
         }
      } 
      while(WordtoGuess.RefreshGame(printGallows)); 
   }//end Play()

   public static void Rules()
   {      
      Scanner keyBd = new Scanner( System.in );
      System.out.println("Hangman Rules");
      System.out.println("Press any key+<Enter> to return to main menu");
      keyBd.next();      
   }//end Rules()   
}//end class hangman
```

Word

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Word
{
   private String word;
   private char[] gword = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' }; //meant to be temporary in place of being sent from Letter
   private int index;
   private ArrayList<String> Words = new ArrayList<String>();
   private ArrayList<Character> goodGuess = new ArrayList<Character>();
   private ArrayList<Character> badGuess = new ArrayList<Character>();

   //constructor
   public Word(String word)
   {
      this.word = word;
   }

   public Word()
   {
      String word;
   } 
   //accesor methods
   public String getWord()
   {
      return word;
   }

   //mutator methods
   public void setWord(String word)
   {
     this.word = word;
   }

   public void setIndex(int index)
   {
      this.index = index;
   }

   public char[] setgword(char letter)
   {
      word = Words.get( index );
      gword = new char[ word.length() ];

      for( int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) 
      {
         gword[i] = '_';
      }
      return gword;
   }

   public char[] CompareGuess( char letter , Gallows printGallows ) 
   {
      boolean isSame = true; 
      for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) 
      {
         if ( gword[ i ] == '_' ) 
         {
            if ( word.charAt( i ) == letter ) 
            {
               gword[ i ] = letter;
            }
         }
      }
      return gword;
   }

   public boolean Win()
   {
      for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
      {
         if (gword[i] == '_')
         {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;      
   }

   public boolean ContainsGuess( char letter ) 
   {
      for ( int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++ ) 
      {
         if ( word.charAt( i ) == letter ) 
         {
            goodGuess.add( letter );
            return true;
         }
      }
      badGuess.add( letter );
      return false;
   }

   public boolean Contains ( char letter ) 
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < goodGuess.size(); i++ ) 
      {
         if ( goodGuess.get( i ) == letter ) 
         {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }

   public boolean NotContain ( char letter ) 
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < badGuess.size(); i++ ) 
      {
         if ( badGuess.get( i ) == letter ) 
         {
         return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }

   public boolean RefreshGame( Gallows printGallows ) 
   {
      if (!Win())
      {
         System.out.println("Good job you WIN!!!!");
      }
      else
      {
         printGallows.printGallows();
      }      
      printGallows.printGallows();
      goodGuess.clear();
      badGuess.clear();
      printGallows.setGuesses( 0 );
      System.out.printf("Your word was %s\n ",word); 
      return false;
   }

   //other Methods
   public String toString()
   {
      return String.format("your word is %s",word);
   }//end toString()              
}//end class Word
```

Letter

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Letter
{
   private char letter;
   Word gword = new Word();

   //constructor
   public Letter()
   {
      char letter;
   }

   //accesor methods   
   public char getLetter()
   {
      return letter;
   }

   //mutator methods      
   public char guessLetter() 
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

      System.out.println( "\nGuess a letter: " );
      String letters = input.nextLine();
      this.letter = letters.charAt(0);
      //gword.setgword(letter); doesnt work properly with sending the input to gword in word file
      return letter;
   }   

   //other Methods
   public String toString()
   {
      return String.format("your letter is: %c",letter);
   }//end toString()         
}//end class Letter
```

Gallows

```
public class Gallows 
{
   private int badGuess;

   public Gallows() 
   {
      int badGuess = 0;
   }

   public int setGuesses() 
   {
      return badGuess++;
   }

   public int setGuesses( int badGuess) 
   {
      this.badGuess = badGuess;
      return badGuess;
   }

   public int getGuesses() 
   {
      return badGuess;
   }

   public boolean hasGuesses() 
   {
      if ( badGuess < 6 ) 
      {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   public void printGallows() 
   {
      switch (badGuess)
      {
         case 1:
            System.out.println(" --\n o |\n   |\n   |\n_____\n");    //head
            System.out.println("You only have 5 chances left!");
            break;
         case 2: 
            System.out.println(" --\n o |\n/  |\n   |\n_____\n");    //head + left arm
            System.out.println("You only have 4 chances left!");
            break;
         case 3: 
            System.out.println(" --\n o |\n/| |\n   |\n_____\n");    //head + left arm + body
            System.out.println("You only have 3 chances left!");
            break;
         case 4: 
            System.out.println(" --\n o |\n/|\\|\n   |\n_____\n");   //head + left arm + body + right arm
            System.out.println("You only have 2 chances left!");
            break;
         case 5: 
            System.out.println(" --\n o |\n/|\\|\n/  |\n_____\n");   //head + left arm + body + right arm + left leg
            System.out.println("You only have 1 chances left!");
            break;
         case 6:
            System.out.println(" --\n o |\n/|\\|\n/ \\|\n_____\n");  //head + left arm + body + right arm + left leg + right leg
            System.out.println("you lose! better luck next time!");
            break;  
      }//end switch
   }//end printGallows(); 
}//end class Gallows
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `setgword()` to do. The method returns a char array. Also, you are creating a new array empty array in the method. What exactly no you want that method to do?

Comment: I would have to read more in detail your code, but be aware that when you push a letter you're not going to a different line until you press enter. You'll keep reading the first char until you effectively skip to the next line. I would use a nextChar method, then close the System.in pipe.

Comment: setgword() is supposed to be coming from the Letter file where the user types which letter to guess, but when I was using it it would make gword "null" and cause the program to throw the NullPointerException

Comment: My guess is that the problem lies in Gallows, could you please post that?

Comment: Gallows has been added, thanks again guys for taking the time to check it out

Comment: Two things in your `setgword()`. 1) `index` may have never been initialized, that will cause a NullPointerException. 2)Also `Words` may have never been given `Character` values.

Comment: I was having problems with index and the word before, but fixed them both and printed them out to make sure that they weren't "null" so I know that they are at least being sent to the Word class

Comment: @Alex I also have noticed that when I did print the input word from the goodGuess array, it wouldn't display the input letter until I was entering the next letter

Answer (score 0):

I have found your error, but I got to say, you really have some redundant code in here.

Your main problem was you were not keeping track of your progress. You can find what I changed below

In HangmanGame

```
public static void Play()
{  
    Letter guesses = new Letter();
    Gallows printGallows = new Gallows();
    //WordToGuess is not initialized here 
    String YourHint = "";     
            //...
            //Not changed anything here                
            //...
    Random rnum = new Random();
    int n;
    System.out.println("start game");
    n = rnum.nextInt(10);


            //WordtoGuess is initialized here, after you have chosen a random number. 
            //Also, note how I didn't use the empty constructor, I am using the one that takes 
            //the word as its input - that constructor is changed in the Word class
    Word WordtoGuess = new Word(Words[n]);


    String hint = Hints.get(n);
    System.out.println("You have 6 chances to guess the word, good luck!!");
    System.out.println(" --\n   |\n   |\n   |\n_____\n");    //gallows
    do{
        while( printGallows.hasGuesses() && WordtoGuess.Win()) //I uncommented this part
        {                                                          
                //Nothing changed here
        }
    }
    while(WordtoGuess.RefreshGame(printGallows)); 
}//end Play()
```

And in the Word class:

```
public Word(String word)
{
    this.word = word;
    //The below lines of code is added. This initializes an array of characters 
    //that hold the lines to guess. Every character is initialized to an underscore
    //'_', since you are checking  this array for underscores. 
    gword = new char[word.length()];
    for (int i=0;i<gword.length;i++){
        gword[i] = '_';
    }
}
```

But, as I've said, this code could be cleaner. You could just use a single method for printing the gallows, keep 2 char arrays - one for the word that is being guessed and another to keep track, keep an ArrayList for checking whether a character has already been entered, and an integer for keeping the number of wrong guesses.

Comment: oh nice thanks for your help, I was able to add some other things and make it work, at least as for what I needed it to do. I also did go through and deleted all of the code that didn't need to be there and it looks a lot better now, could still use a lot of work for functionality and such but yeah. thanks again for your time and going through all of that to help me out.